# Random_state's contribution to accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

Okay, this is interesting..
I executed the same code a couple of times and each time I got a different `accuracy_score`.
I figured that I was not using any `random_state` value while `train_test splitting`. so I used `random_state=0` and got consistent `Accuracy_score` of 82%. but...
then I thought to give it a try with different `random_state` number and I set `random_state=128` and `Accuracy_score` becomes 84%.
Now I need to understand why is that and how `random_state` affects the accuracy of the model.
Outputs are as below:
**1> without random_state:**

```
runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[90 22]
 [21 46]]
0.7597765363128491

runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[104  16]
 [ 14  45]]
0.8324022346368715

runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[90 18]
 [12 59]]
0.8324022346368715

runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[99  9]
 [19 52]]
0.8435754189944135
```

**2> with random_state = 128 (Accuracy_score = 84%)**

```
runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[106  13]
 [ 15  45]]
0.8435754189944135

runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[106  13]
 [ 15  45]]
0.8435754189944135
```

**3> with random_state = 0 (Accuracy_score = 82%)**

```
runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[93 17]
 [15 54]]
0.8212290502793296

runfile('C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic/Colab File.py', wdir='C:/Users/spark/OneDrive/Documents/Machine Learing/Datasets/Titanic')

: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.

[[93 17]
 [15 54]]
0.8212290502793296
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `random_state` is going to make sure your code outputs the same results each time, by doing the same exact data splits each time. This is mostly helpful for your initial train/test split, and for creating code that others can replicate exactly.

### Splitting the data the same vs. differently

The first thing to understand is that if you don't use `random_state`, then the data will be split *differently* each time, which means that your training set and test sets will be different. This might not make a huge different, but it will result in *slight* variations in your model parameters / accuracy / etc. If you do set `random_state` to the same value each time, like `random_state=0`, then the data will be split the same way each time.

### Each random_state results in a different split

The second thing to understand is that *each* `random_state` value will result in different splits and different behavior. So you need to keep `random_state` as the same value if you want to be able to replicate results.

### Your model can have multiple random_state pieces

The third thing to understand is that multiple pieces of your model might have randomness in them. For example, your `train_test_split` can accept `random_state`, but so can `RandomForestClassifier`. So in order to get the *exact* same results each time, you'll need to set `random_state` for each piece of your model that has randomness in it.

### Conclusions

If you're using `random_state` to do your initial train/test split, you're going to want to set it once and use that split going forward to avoid overfitting to your test set.

Generally speaking, you can use cross-validation to assess the accuracy of your model and not worry too much about the `random_state`.

**A very important note is that you should not use `random_state` to try to improve the accuracy of your model.** This is by definition going to result in your model overfitting your data, and not generalizing as well to unseen data.